# Retrofit POST запрос с параметром в Body

Tags: android, retrofit

Использую Retrofit2. Нужно отправить POST запрос с параметрами guid=1 так что-бы этот запрос шел в body.

```
 @POST("/api/1/model")
 Call<ApiModelJson> getPostClub(@Body User body);
```

Класс User

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("guid")
String guid;



public User(String guid ) {
    this.guid = guid;

}
```

}

Запускаю так

```
User user =new User ("1");
    Call<ApiModelJson> call = service.getPostClub(user);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiModelJson>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ApiModelJson> response) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Status Code = " + response.code());
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                // request successful (status code 200, 201)

                ApiModelJson result = response.body();

            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Соединение проходит нормально но в ответ я ничего не получаю.

Вот еще код

```
 public static WorldClassApiInterface getClient() {
    if (WordClassApiInterface == null) {

        OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                return response;
            }
        });

        Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverter(String.class, new ToStringConverter())
                .client(okClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        WordClassApiInterface = client.create(WorldClassApiInterface.class);
    }
    return WordClassApiInterface ;
}
```

Comment: то есть у Вас в onResponse ответ с сервера не приходит?

Comment: Приходит но с ошибкой. Те кто сервер настраивал сказали они переделали так что бы параметр guid в body принимать. До этого через @Field работало прекрасно. А вот как в body передать я никак не соображу. Приходит вот что {"body":{"model":[]},"datetime":1446129253,"type":"error"}

Comment: Я не пользовался данной Http-client-ом, но что-то мне подсказывает что вы в параметре пытаетесь передать объект User, а не его значение guid. Могу ошибаться

Comment: А можете посоветовать другой клиент?

Comment: я использую вот этот http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: Вы в body вот такую штуку передаете `{ "guid":"1" }` вы уточните на серверной стороне в каком формате они запрос ждут.